# Lookup table in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe in Spark with no clearly defined schema that I want to use as a lookup table. For example, the dataframe below:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|lookupcolumn                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6]                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The schema would look like this:

```
 |-- lookupcolumn: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key5: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key6: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm saying "schema not clearly defined" since the number of keys is unknown while the data is being read, so I leave it to Spark to infer the schema.

Now, if I have another dataframe with a column as below:

```
+-----------------+
|       datacolumn|
+-----------------+
|         key1    |
|         key3    |
|         key5    |
|         key2    |
|         key4    |
+-----------------+
```

and I want the result to be:

```
+-----------------+
|     resultcolumn|
+-----------------+
|         val1    |
|         val3    |
|         val5    |
|         val2    |
|         val4    |
+-----------------+
```

I tried a `UDF` like this:

```
val get_val = udf((keyindex: String) => {
    val res = lookupDf.select($"lookupcolumn"(keyindex).alias("result"))
    res.head.toString
})
```

But it throws a Null Pointer exception error.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the `UDF`, and if there's a better/simpler way of doing this lookup in Spark?

Comment: is your lookup dataframe only one rowed or multiple rowed?

Comment: It has only one row. I guess it would be easier if I could just explode it to multiple rows with key and value in different columns, so I could then do a join, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Umm, nope. The resultcolumn has values while the datacolumn has keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the lookup table is quite small, in this case it would make more sense to collect it to the driver and convert it to a normal `Map`. Then use this `Map` in the `UDF` function. It can be done in many way, for example like this:

```
val values = lookupDf.select("lookupcolumn.*").head.toSeq.map(_.toString)
val keys = lookupDf.select("lookupcolumn.*").columns
val lookup_map = keys.zip(values).toMap
```

Using the above `lookup_map` variable, the `UDF` will simply be:

```
val lookup = udf((key: String) => lookup_map.get(key))
```

And the final dataframe can be obtained by:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("resultcolumn", lookup($"datacolumn"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But is there a way to have the UDF return null when the key is not in the table? Currently it throws an error.

Comment: @PramodKumar: Yes, it is possible. I changed the udf slightly, now it should return null when the key does not exists. It would also be possible to return a default value by changing `get()` to `getOrElse()`.